# Can I define the order in which event listeners / subscribers are called in doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two event subscribers A and B. Both subscribed to the `onFlush` event.

I want to make sure that `a::onFlush()` is always called before `B::onFlush()`.
I can't find any resource on this in the documentation.

I use symfony2 so it would be great if I could just pass the value in in the service definition.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add a priority to your service tag. The higher the priority the earlier it will run.

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: Acme\SearchBundle\EventListener\SearchIndexer
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, priority: 100 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just discovered this on my own. It's worth mentioning that it also works with subscribers.

Comment: Initial testing here seems to indicate that priority setting on subscribers does not seem to work. (Using current symfony / doctrine )

Comment: @Jan The above answer is correct. If you think you have found a bug within the Symfony code you should contact the developers on github.