# How to make the method annotated with @PrePersist run before a property is set by @Timestampable?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an Entity

```
class Foo{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function bar()
    {
        $this->createdAt->getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the Foo::bar() is run before the TimestampableListener has the opportunity to set the proper value of `$this->createdAt`.

I was trying tu change the priority of the event listener in services.yml (as hinted in [Can I define the order in which event listeners / subscribers are called in doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467970/can-i-define-the-order-in-which-event-listeners-subscribers-are-called-in-doct)), but it does not work.

Comment: @chalasr: I am new to this, but why would you edit my post? timestamptz was a correct type.

Comment: Really sorry, I believed it was a mistake ! It's the first time I see this type.

Comment: @chalasr, it's OK. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in Doctrine's [ListenersInvoker](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/ListenersInvoker.php#L74) the `LifecycleCallbacks` are invoked before the `EntityListeners`, so the TimestampableListener will never run before the `PrePersist` annotation.

You could either create your own EntityListener that listens to the `prePersist` event and calls your `bar` method and use the priority to change the order.
Or, in case of defining the `createdAt`, you could avoid using Timestampable and set the `createdAt` value in the constructor manually.

Comment: EntityListener did the job.