# How to control Doctrine Event subscriber priorities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, listener

I have an entity which I have two separate event subscribers listen to postPersist and postUpdate events to trigger particular actions. In the EventDispatcher component in Symfony the listeners could have priority attached to them but I do not seem to find the priority option for Doctrine events. Is there a way to have the subscribers prioritized or Doctrine event dispatcher doesn't support it, I really can't seem to find the right option for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your event listeners as a service and then you can set priority.

E.g. from this answer.

[Can I define the order in which event listeners / subscribers are called in doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467970/can-i-define-the-order-in-which-event-listeners-subscribers-are-called-in-doct)

Comment: But of course, how silly of me to forget the service definitions. I tried to do it via the array in the `getSubscribedEvents` method. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to specify the priority inside `getSubscribedEvents()` you should try with `['eventName' => ['methodName', $priority]]`

Comment: This only works with Symfony events subscribers, not with Doctrine event subscribers. Doctrine subscribers must be defined in services.yaml to set the priority and the subscriber methods names must be the same as the event name : prePersist, postUpdate.. (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers)